# Rails & Heroku - Migrating Database Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm attempting to deploy my Rails project to Heroku for the first time and I'm getting an error in my database migration. It seems to be the result of removing a column from my database but I'm lost from there and don't know what steps to take next. All migrations are up to date and it works fine in development mode. The following is the error message that I'm getting:

```
D, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.361851 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(5611133814980990205)
D, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.377916 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
I, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.379169 #4]  INFO -- : Migrating to RemoveCoinFromQuestions (20180121170335)
D, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.384613 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.6ms)  BEGIN
== 20180121170335 RemoveCoinFromQuestions: migrating ==========================
-- remove_column(:questions, :coin, :string)
D, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.387289 #4] DEBUG -- :    (2.3ms)  ALTER TABLE "questions" DROP "coin"
D, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.388188 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2018-01-25T03:33:27.389388 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.8ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(5611133814980990205)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "coin" of relation "questions" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "questions" DROP "coin"
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:73:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:46:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:185:in `yield_shares'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:45:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:72:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:611:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:603:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:71:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:576:in `remove_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:849:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:818:in `block in say_with_time'
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180125010531) do

  create_table "coins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "link_name"
    t.string "currency_name"
    t.string "currency_abbrev"
    t.float "volume_usd"
    t.float "volume_btc"
    t.string "picture"
    t.string "website1"
    t.string "website2"
    t.string "website3"
    t.string "website4"
    t.string "website5"
    t.string "website6"
    t.string "website7"
    t.string "website8"
    t.text "question1"
    t.text "question2"
    t.text "question3"
    t.text "question4"
    t.text "question5"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "permalink"
    t.string "genre"
    t.integer "moderator_id"
  end

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "coin_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.boolean "accepted", default: false
    t.integer "upvotes", default: 0
    t.integer "downvotes", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "link"
    t.string "picture"
    t.date "date"
    t.time "time"
  end

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "ques_num"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "coin_id"
    t.boolean "accepted"
    t.index ["coin_id"], name: "index_questions_on_coin_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_questions_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "fname"
    t.string "lname"
    t.string "wallet"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.boolean "moderator", default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  create_table "views", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_views_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_views_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction here, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is clearly saying `column "coin" of relation "questions" does not exist` . and you try to drop coin relation

Comment: It doesn't exist because it got dropped. Should I just delete that file then? Sorry for my ignorance, this is my first time doing this.

Comment: No, never ever delete migration file. for overcome this issue. you can just comment the code of that file if you don't want it.

Comment: Are you getting the error when running `heroku run rake db:migrate`? If so, have you tried loading your schema instead?

Comment: @jvillian i don't think schema load is good choice, because whenever any other try to setup the project he might be get this error again. also what about other future migrations ?

Comment: @Vishal - I'm not sure the [official rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you) agrees with you: "There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler and faster to just load into the database a description of the current schema." But, what do they know?

Comment: I commented out the line in the migration. I think I actually did delete a prior file where I had added the column so there was an extra remove column.